# $\int_A \partial_jf(x)dx = \int_{B} f(x) \frac{x_j}{r} d\sigma(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n).$ Let $r>0,$ and put $A= \{x\in \mathbb R^n: |x|<r \}, B= \{ x\in \mathbb R^n : |x|=r \}.$

> Can we say 
>   $$\int_A  \partial_jf(x)dx = \int_{B} f(x) \frac{x_j}{r} d\sigma(x)$$
>   where $d\sigma $ is a surface measure on $\{x\in \mathbb R^n: |x|=1\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the key step is to write the single variable derivative as a divergence: define the vector field $F:ℝ^n \to ℝ^n$ by $F := (0,\dots f ,\dots ,0)$, where the only nonzero component is in the $j$th component. Then notice by Divergence Theorem,

$$ \int_{|x|<r}\partial_j f \, dx = \int_{|x|<r} \nabla \cdot F dx = \int_{|x|=r} F\cdot\vec{N} \,d\sigma = \int_{|x|=r} fN_j \,d\sigma $$

Where $\vec{N} = (N_1,\dots,N_n)$ is the unit outward normal. We finish by noting that the normal to $x\in \{|y|=r\}$ is proportional to $x$ itself.

Comment: @CK: Thanks. Please would you explain bit more.  What is $\vec{n}$ here?  Why $F\cdot \vec{n}= f(\vec{n})_j$?  How should I prove $f(\vec{n})_j= f(x) \frac{x_j}{r}$? Thanks..

Comment: $f(\vec{n})_j$ was not meant to be evaluation of $f$. I have made the notation clearer. 

$N$ comes from the application of Divergence theorem.

The last sentence of the answer explains how to compute the normal.